# Java Android, loop through all getters

Tags: java, android

I have a model like below:

```
public class Shifts{

    private double h00;
    private double h01;
    private double h02;
    private double h03;

    public Shifts() {
    }

    public Shifts(double h00, double h01, double h02, double h03) {
        this.h00 = h00;
        this.h01 = h01;
        this.h02 = h02;
        this.h03 = h03;
    }

    public double getH00() {
        return h00;
    }

    public void setH00(double h00) {
        this.h00 = h00;
    }

    public double getH01() {
        return h01;
    }

    public void setH01(double h01) {
        this.h01 = h01;
    }

    public double getH02() {
        return h02;
    }

    public void setH02(double h02) {
        this.h02 = h02;
    }

    public double getH03() {
        return h03;
    }

    public void setH03(double h03) {
        this.h03 = h03;
    }
}
```

I'm calling this model in a recycle adapter to update the UI and on the `onBindViewHolder`, I do like this:

```
holder.h00.setText(fooList.get(position).getH00()));
holder.h01.setText(fooList.get(position).getH01()));
holder.h02.setText(fooList.get(position).getH02()));
holder.h03.setText(fooList.get(position).getH03()));
```

In reality, this model has a lot of getters and setters and I was trying to loop through them so I can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < holder.shift_layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                //shift_layout is the Layout which holds all the views
                View v = holder.shift_layout.getChildAt(i);
                if (v instanceof TextView) {

                    v.setText(Hour(fooList.get(position).getGetter()));
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to use Java reflection or any method to loop through all getters of a model and then invoke them?

Looking over the SO I found some answers but with not any success to invoke the getters.

Comment: Create annotation processor, define you annotation, put it over class and process further.

Comment: @silentsudo That could be the base of a nice answer actually.

Comment: Note that unless you have a reason for the no-parameter constructor where all the fields are set to `0.0`, I'd seriously suggest to remove it. If it is seriously a Bean (bleh) then you may need to keep it and implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers provided, especially Magnus, definitely get the job done. They are valid answers. The only difference between this solution and the others is that this will ensure that the method name starts with `getH` which seems to be pattern. It also checks if the return type is of type double to help ensure the correct method is being returned.

```java
        Shifts shifts = new Shifts(1, 2, 3, 4);

        Method[] methods = shifts.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("getH") && method.getReturnType() == double.class) {
                double value = (double) method.invoke(shifts);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to come in a solution. Thank you again

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 3):

This code iterates over all methods of the class obj and if method name starts with 'get' it invokes the method m on instance obj and assigns the result to object:

```
final Object obj;    
for (Method m : obj.getClass().getMethods())
    if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
      final Object object = m.invoke(obj);
      // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of an explanation with your answer? I guess this one is pretty easy to read, but generally we try and avoid code-only answers at SO...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way you can loop through getters by reflections. You should first make some kind of list with names of attributes. 
I did it once with HashMap and setters, then I iterated through that hash map with:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    var setterName = "set" + entry.getKey().toUpperCase();
    Method setter = instanceOfMyClassWithSetters.getClass().getMethod(setterName, Integer.class);
    setter.invoke(instanceOfMyClassWithSetters, entry.getValue());
}
```

That `Integer.class` is a setter parameter so I suppose you don't need that part.

Comment: Heads up I believe OP wants the getters so they can retrieve all values, and they should be double, not integer.